# How add noscript tag below image in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, lazy-loading, noscript

I am using lazy loading for my images and as [Google pointed out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1980&v=PFwUbgvpdaQ) it is crucial to add a noscript tag below each img.

I want to add a noscript tag below every image in the **Wordpress editor**, something like:

```
<figure>
   <img src="img.jpg">
   <nocript><img src="img.jp"></noscript>
   <figcaption> Caption</figcaption>
<figure>
```

But I can't :(

This is my function in PHP.

```
add_filter('the_content', function ($content) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($post->post_content);
    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName( 'img' ) as $img) {
        if ( $img->hasAttribute( 'src' )) {
         $src_attr = $img->getAttribute( 'src' );
         $noscript      = $dom->createElement( 'noscript' );
         $noscript_node = $img->parentNode->insertBefore( $noscript, $img );
         $noscript_img  = $dom->createElement( 'IMG' );
         $new_img = $noscript_node->appendChild( $noscript_img );
         $new_img->setAttribute( 'src', $src_attr );
         $content = $dom->saveHTML();
      }
    };

    return $content;
});
```

Help, please :D

Comment: what does the $content returns?

Comment: it should return the noscript tag but nothing is being returned on the DOM

Comment: that I understand, I ask currently, what does the $content contains? did you var_dump it?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about var_dump (JS Developer) The whole post is being returned

Comment: You got me thinking... I'm trying a similar version of your code using JS myself, do you have a simple example for a parallel case in JS maybe?

Comment: No, but with I don't want to do it with JS because Google might not read it.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1980&v=PFwUbgvpdaQ in this conference they explain that sometimes they can't read JS. That's why I am using PHP instead of JS.

Comment: (I actually need a solution for myself... similar to you code, only in JS...)

Answer (score 0):

The thing to notice with foreach loops, when updating an existing object (or array), if working by reference

By default, foreach loops creates a copy of the items and runs on that. to work with the actual object, you shoukd add the & before

I would also notice using temp vars for the real dom allocation:
creating temp vars and use their result for insertion to the object

But it should work

I also got the saveHTML out of the loop, since there is no need for intermediary saves

hope that helps

below with the &$img

```
add_filter('the_content', function ($content) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($post->post_content);
    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName( 'img' ) as &$img) {
        if ( $img->hasAttribute( 'src' )) {
         $src_attr = $img->getAttribute( 'src' );
         $noscript      = $dom->createElement( 'noscript' );
         $noscript_node = $img->parentNode->insertBefore( $noscript, $img );
         $noscript_img  = $dom->createElement( 'IMG' );
         $new_img = $noscript_node->appendChild( $noscript_img );
         $new_img->setAttribute( 'src', $src_attr );
      }
    };
 $content = $dom->saveHTML();

    return $content;
});
```

Comment: There is an error because when I pasted the code the whole post is not being displayed, any other idea?

Comment: @Alfrex92 will check l

Comment: I removed the ; from the foreach closing}, I figured it was not needed... maybw it was. I fixed that